# Using dependencies from zip archive in maven install

Tags: java, maven

I have the zip archive libs.zip which contains .jar files.

Is it possible to unpack libs.zip and compile the project with libraries from zip archive?

Comment: Simple answer: No. Easiest way to unpack them and deploy them into a repository manager and use them as usual dependencies...a more unusual way to unpack them and install via maven into local repo...

Comment: It is worth noting that each .jar file is in fact a compressed zip file, so keeping all of the .jar files in a single zip file does not save any space.